# Rename file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I want to move a file to another directory in my server.
So I use rename, but i have an issue :

```
Message:rename(localhost:8888/asset/upload/pdf/161115_1231_maj.pdf,localhost:8888/asset/upload/del/pdf/161115_1231_maj.pdf): No such file or directory
```

But, when i copy paste the link in my browser, the link is good, so i don't understand why rename doesn't work. I also tried to use copy, move_uploaded_file, with absolute path or not.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

Use the filepath, not the URL. In other words, `/var/www/html/asset.....` (or where ever it is) instead of "localhost"

---

EDIT...

Based on your comments you say you're using MAMP, but your stuff is located in a WAMP folder. MAMP is for Mac only and doesn't run on Windows and WAMP is for Windows only and doesn't run on Mac, so your first step is to figure out which one your using and place your files in the correct directories because the two are not compatible with each other..

If you want your file to work on both the server and your development machine without changing paths you can always determine the absolute path with PHP..

Assume you have a file structure like this

```
/webroot
   index.php
/uploads
   myfile.pdf
   /del
```

You can get the full path to the current file like this

```
$Full_path_to_current_file = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

If you put that in your index file, it would look like this: `/full/path/to/my/webroot`

Now you can simply do

```
rename("$Full_path_to_current_file/uploads/myfile.pdf", "$Full_path_to_current_file/uploads/del/myfile.pdf");
```

that way you don't have to have two separate versions of the file with different paths.

---

EDIT 2

The next probable cause is lack of permissions. Make sure that PHP has access to the file in question. Run this in the command line and see if that helps (obviously use your real path though)

`sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/webroot`

Don't do that on the server though, if you have to do it on the server just change the permission of the file itself. The easiest way to change the permission of a file on the server is to use FileZilla. Just FTP into the server, right click on the remote file and choose "file permissions." Then you can set the correct permissions as needed.

Comment: I try to do this, I use mamp, so i can choose the dir, and i choose a dir call wamp. So my filepath should be `/wamp/www/asset....` but i got the same error : `Message: rename(/wamp/www/asset/upload/pdf/161115_1231_maj.pdf,/wamp/www/asset/upload/del/pdf/161115_1231_maj.pdf): No such file or directory`

Comment: I try with the full path `/User...` the file is renamed, but I still have the same issue, i don't know why, probably because rename function is done in my computer, and not in the server (who is local)

Comment: I try to move the file out of the server with the full path, and it doesn't work, so I guess i should have to use full path, but I don't understand why i have an issue when I try then it work

Comment: @CorentinVerpillat - I edited the answer. If that answered your question please hit the checkmark, if it was otherwise helpful please consider upvoting. good luck.

Comment: I just choose a dir who has wamp as name, but there is no error with that, it's just a name no worrie. i'm going to use realpath like you say, but the problem is that the file is well deleted but i have the same issue

Comment: i try with realpath, but it's same issue

Comment: I change permissions of my dir, and it change change nothing, i also change the permissions of the file that i was going to delete, and i had the same issue.
Sorry for the time i made to answer, i was in "holliday"

Comment: the only thing left is to check the path itself. your path simply must be wrong.

Comment: if my path is wrong, why the file is renamed ? If it was wrong, nothing should happen

Comment: i'm glad you figured it out. if my answer helped please hit the checkmark by the answer.

Comment: i'm still blocked, i have the error message, but the file is renamed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use quotation marks:

```
Message:rename("localhost:8888/asset/upload/pdf/161115_1231_maj.pdf","localhost:8888/asset/upload/del/pdf/161115_1231_maj.pdf"): "No such file or directory"
```

Comment: the error message always omits the quotes. that's an error message, not his code. he obviously did use the quotes or else he would have gotten a parser error..